# How can I define a jquery var to a php variable?

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have this simple question I've been looking for and workin on for awhile and I can't seem to get it. Heres my code.

```
<script>

 function calculate() {
    var total = (parseInt($('#studenttut option:selected').val()) + parseInt($('#campusrb>option:selected').val())) * parseInt($('#yearsatten>option:selected').val());
    $("#total").html("<table width='100%'><tr><td>Your calculated cost is: $" + total +"</td>" +
    "<td align='right'>" +
    "<?php $calculatedCost = " + total + ";" +
    " ?>");

    }
</script>
```

Any suggestion on how I can define a jquery var to a php variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set jquery variable to PHP .. since PHP is server side code and Javascript is client side.... however you can use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send the var to server side.. **or** use FORM to post the var to server... you can use `val()` to place the value to the form..

```
 $('#inputID').val(total);
```

and post the form

Answer (score 1):

You can not assign value of javascript variable to php variable using javascript on client rather you can use ajax call to send the value top php code on server and use it where you need.

Comment: Well I want to add the variable to a texbox so I can post it in the database

Comment: To clarify, there is no way to "convert" a JavaScript variable to a PHP variable; your JavaScript code is running on your clients' computers and will have to send the value of those variables to your PHP script via AJAX or posting your form.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because `jQuery` is client side script whereas `PHP` is server side script. Please consider the difference..

Answer (score 0):

Try to get it in a hidden input and post it when required.:

```
"<td align='right'>" +
"<input type='hidden' id='total' value='" + total + "/>");
```